# Laravel при post запросе выдается ошибка 405

Tags: php, laravel, route, crud, backpack

Имеется Laravel с установленным backpack. Настроил custom.php таким образом, что бы все не указанные выше маршруты падали в fallback. С GET и HEAD запросами все в порядке. Однако при отправке POST(или других) запроса выдается ошибка 405.
Файл custom.php

```
    Route::group([
    'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
], function () {
    Route::crud('user', 'UserCrudController');
    Route::crud('operator', 'OperatorCrudController');
    Route::crud('provider', 'ProviderCrudController');

    Route::fallback('DefaultController@index');
});
```

api.php

```
Route::middleware([])->group(function () {
    Route::post('default', OpenApiController::class.'@open')
        ->withoutMiddleware(['api'])
        ->middleware(['api.no.auth'])
        ->name('default');
    /*пробую указать тут маршрут, но не находит контроллер, даже если подключаешь его в use*/
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть кому-то пригодится.
Видимо fallback обрабатывает только методы GET и HEAD. Что бы ловить все входящие маршруты на всех методах, не описанные в правилах выше использовал any

```
Route::any('{any}', 'DefaultController@index');
```

Comment: Если посмотреть сорцы, fallback() добавляет GET-роут: `public function fallback($action) {
        $placeholder = 'fallbackPlaceholder'; return $this->addRoute('GET', "{{$placeholder}}", $action->where($placeholder, '.*')->fallback(); }`. Также чуть выше в сорцах можно увидеть указанный метод `any()` который добавляет абсолютно все методы, которые может принять роутер.

Comment: @TotalPusher, просто почему-то в доках это не написано было. Пришлось методом тыка проверять.

Comment: Документация устаревает в момент своего выхода. Про что-то забывают. Самая актуальная информация, а также "как это работает" - в сорцах. Я до своего коммента вроде бы помнил, что есть any() или all(), но подсмотрел в сорцах. Кликаете в IDE, проваливаетесь в исходный код библиотеки. В ней можно поискать подходящий метод. В PHPStorm есть вкладка Structure - показывает методы/свойства/константы класса. Выключаете private/protected, выключаете константы и свойства. Получается только список публичных методов. Среди них ищите нужный, названия очень понятные. Заодно изучаете что там еще есть.